# AzureReservedIP - AuthenticationFailed: A security token exception occured for the received JWT token

Tags: powershell, azure

I have been trying to reserve a new Public IP in azure but executing any related command I get this error: "AuthenticationFailed: A security token exception occured for the received JWT token".

My connection to azure from the powershell seems to work fine, as I can execute several other commands with it. Also I tried to import the subscription publish setting but the error persists.

Other info: I was granted as "Service administrator" for the subscription.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: can you provide the exacts steps to reproduce? - i.e. exact sequence of PowerShell cmdlets executed.

Comment: Sure. I have followed the 2 links: 
- http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/using-reserved-ip-addresses-with-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines/
- http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

But I also notice that I am getting the same error for all ReservedIP commands. Steps: 
1) Add-AzureAccount
2) Get-AzureReservedIP 
3) Error:  AuthenticationFailed: A security token exception occured for the received JWT token.

Comment: are you using latest version of PowerShell? (0.8.8.1 or newer?) to check use: (Get-Module Azure).Version
Just executed what you rovided with 0.8.8.1 and see no issues, everything works fine.

Comment: I am using the latest version. Just fresh downloaded from the Azure website "http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/". I was reading some other blogs and it might be something related with the Azure Account. Later I will try to remove all the accounts with Remove-AzureAccount and check if I get any luck. Tks!